# Java makefile can't find JAR resource

Tags: java, makefile, jar

I have a problem with this line in a Make file:

```
"%JDK%\bin\Javac" -classpath .;..;..\..\..\inc\Java\com.abbyy.FREngine.jar *.java
```

Error message is saying that the path couldn't be found. 
I'm not familiar with make files at all. Can somebody help me with this?
What does %JDK% mean?
And what does this ".;..;......" mean? This can't be right. I tried to modify the path a few times to link directly to the jar file but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%JDK% points to location specified by environment variable.

Take a look here for more info: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

This line

```
-classpath .;..;..\..\..\inc\Java\com.abbyy.FREngine.jar
```

tells Java where to look for classes/packages. In your case these are

```
. - directory where you are
.. - directory one level up
..\..\..\inc\Java\com.abbyy.FREngine.jar - jar file that is few levels up
```

and you compile all java files using *.java

What you need to do, is to make sure that %JDK% points to your JDK installation and you have to make sure that you have provided proper location of jar file.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful answer.